# Get new value and auto removing previous value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkbox with jQuery to get the checked checkbox value by name attribute. My question is how to make the checkbox removing previous checked value and displaying new value.

At current situation, it was joining value, not changing each other.

Here the sample HTML code :

```
<div class="drop-column">
 <label class="column-label"><input class="column-checkbox" type = "checkbox" rel = "All    
   Column" name = "All Filter" />Filter (All Fields)</label>
 <label class="column-label"><input class="column-checkbox" type = "checkbox" rel =    
   "Name" name="Name" />Name</label>
 <label class="column-label"><input class="column-checkbox" type = "checkbox" rel =  
   "Department" name = "Department" />Department</label>
 <label class="column-label"><input class="column-checkbox" type = "checkbox" rel =  
   "Manager" name = "Manager" />Manager</label>
</div>

<div class="filter-by-col-text"></div>
```

and jQuery for do the function

```
$('div.drop-column').delegate('.column-checkbox', 'change', function () {
    var $checked = $('.column-checkbox:checked');

    var rels = [];
    $checked.each(function () {
        rels.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    $('.filter-by-col-text').html(rels);
});
```

Link to fiddle test http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/f6t9M/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('div.drop-column').delegate('.column-checkbox', 'change', function () {
     $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
     $(this).prop('checked','checked');
     var    $checked = $('.column-checkbox:checked');
    var rels;
    $checked.each(function () {
        rels=($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    $('.filter-by-col-text').html(rels);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6t9M/4/)**

Comment: Hi Milind, there is one issue. When we check from All field checkbox to Manager is working fine. But if we back again to check first checkbox, the value didnt change, still showing Manager. Any clue?

Comment: the checkbox array from left to right is "filter>name>department>manager", if we check from left to right is correct. But when we reverse right to left check, or start from any, example: we check manager and then department its not update the value.